# How to form DHCPDISCOVER via scapy on Python?

Tags: scapy, dhcp

I created a request using scapy. It works fine with my eth0 interface. I send a message to the discoverer and i get an offer. But it doesn't work through the wlan0 interface, when I connect to it via wifi and try to send a packet.
Why is this happening ? How to fix it ?

```
from scapy.all import *

conf.checkIPaddr = False


dhcp_discover = Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff',src=RandMAC())  \
                 /IP(src='0.0.0.0',dst='255.255.255.255') \
                 /UDP(sport=68,dport=67) \
                 /BOOTP(op=1, chaddr=RandMAC()) \
                 /DHCP(options=[('message-type','discover'),('end')])

#sendp(dhcp_discover,iface='eth0') # Ok 
sendp(dhcp_discover,iface='wlan0') # not working
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvawq.png)

Comment: Please make sure your image is visible on first sight

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending DHCP Discover using python scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124500/sending-dhcp-discover-using-python-scapy)